# Blender a good robotic simulator for quadcopters / swarm simulations?

Tags: simulator

I'm interested in simulating Quadcopter control and Swarm co-ordinations. Was wondering if Blender or specifically [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/) was going to be good enough? According to the [limitations of MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/what_is_morse.html#but-even-morse-has-its-limitations), it states:

> - MORSE was never meant to be a physically accurate simulator: while we rely on a state-of-the-art physics engine (Bullet), do not expect to accurately simulate robot arm dynamics or fine grasping. Other projects are doing that much better (like OpenGrasp for grasping).
> - While on-going efforts try to tackle this issue, we do not consider MORSE to have a good enough temporal accuracy and time synchronization capabilities for application like hybrid simulation (where some robots are simulated while others are physically operated).

Was wondering if anyone has experience in using blender for these types of applications.

Comment: I haven't worked with any simulators and wouldn't know if they supported quadcopters, but there's a list of [robotics simulators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2533321/610108) on stackoverflow that pre-dates robotics.SE (though it was updated in January) but should still be fairly current.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [v-rep](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/). They say that the program is specifically designed to simulate any robot and support dynamic particles allowing for the creation of engines and propellors. The program even comes with a pre-made quadcopter model.